# CreateValidIdentifier() fails to check name

Tags: c#, codedom, csharpcodeprovider

I am using CreateProvider() to check if a string is good variable name.

```
var codeDomProvider =   CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");
var goodName        =   codeDomProvider.CreateValidIdentifier("ab.cd");
```

surprisingly, it gives me back 'ab.cd'.  Visual Studio never allows such name.  how does this happen?  I tried again with 'System.Type':

```
var codeDomProvider =   CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");
var goodName        =   codeDomProvider.CreateValidIdentifier("System.Type");
```

it gives me back 'System.Type'.  this is troubling.

Comment: have you consulted with the [Codedom Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yzxs14d(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: OK, I read it.  what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation for `CreateValidIdentifier()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.createvalididentifier) says:

> CreateValidIdentifier tests whether the identifier conflicts with reserved or language keywords, and if so, attempts to return a valid identifier name that does not conflict.

So, it's not meant as a general-purpose identifier validation method. I believe it's mostly meant for multi-language environments, where an identifier might conflict with a keyword in one language, but not in others.

I think what you're looking for is [`IsValidIdentifier()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.isvalididentifier):

> This method tests whether an identifier is valid.

And for your values, it indeed returns `false`. This will tell you that an identifier is not valid, but it won't tell you how to fix it, you will have to figure that out yourself. Looking at [the source of `IsValidIdentifier()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/microsoft/csharp/csharpcodeprovider.cs,7b5c20ff8d28dfa7) might help with that.

Comment: thanks.  I created my own method to deal with the situation.